# Blur/Onblur not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blur, onblur

I've been trying to change the border-color of a textarea when the focus gets out, but it's not doing anything, not even if I'm only trying to alert something.

These are the methods I've tried so far:

The first:

```
$('#idname').on('blur', function() {
     alert(1);
});
```

The second:

```
document.getElementById('idname').onblur() = function () {
     alert(1);
}
```

The third:

```
function redBlur() {
     alert(1);
}
```

And the html:

```
<textarea rows="1" cols="10" type="email" id="idname" name="title" onblur="redBlur()"></textarea>
```

```js
$('#idname').on('blur', function() {
     alert(1);
});

document.getElementById('idname').onblur() = function () {
     alert(1);
}
function redBlur() {
     alert(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="1" cols="10" type="email" id="idname" name="title" onblur="redBlur()"></textarea>
```

Do you have any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Add your HTML also

Comment: Add your full code here

Comment: is the element dynamically added?or have same id?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? And is your JavaScript being loaded after your HTML or wrapped in an on ready block?

Comment: You don't need JS to change the border color of an element on focus/blur - CSS can do that: https://jsfiddle.net/b1wfzhwn/

Comment: Make sure you have the jquery library loaded correctly and you don't have errors in the console.

Comment: The element has the same id, and the javascript is wrapped in an on ready block before the html.

Comment: The CSS doesn't help because I don't want the alert/border color change before the focus gets on the input at least once.

Comment: First `.onBlur()=...` is wrong. Second, when you use script to add handlers, make sure, your DOM is rendered before. But when you do `obBlur="..."` then your script should render before and function should be globally accessible. Try using a delegate: `$(document).bind("eventName", "#id", function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, you need to remove the parentheses after the `onblur`, otherwise it's trying to invoke the existing handler rather than assigning a new handler. It's also unusual to chain methods directly after using `getElementById`. Try this:

```
var field = document.getElementById('idname');
field.addEventListener('blur', function () {
     alert(1);
});
```

Comment: I tried both to simply remove the parantheses and to assign the element to a variable first like in your example, but it didn't work either way... Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="test"></textarea>
    <script>
            $(function(){
            $('#test').on('blur', function (){
                    $('#test').css('border-color', 'red');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```